# Error establishing a database connection with XAMPP

Tags: database, local-installation

I'm just getting started with Wordpress, and currently using an XAMPP server to try and get a local installation working. The localhost environment is working fine, and I've successfully [followed the steps here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Using_phpMyAdmin) to create a database and user account for Wordpress using phpMyAdmin.

However, when navigating to `localhost/wordpress` to begin the Wordpress installation and enter my credentials into the relevant fields, I get the error:

> #### Error establishing a database connection

I also discovered through a fluke that when I enter no password at all in the password field, I get a different, more specific error that claims my credentials are correct:

> #### Can’t select database
>
> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the hashim_wordpress database.
>
> Are you sure it exists?
>
> Does the user Hashim have permission to use the hashim_wordpress database? On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_hashim_wordpress. Could that be the problem?

However, this can't be the case as that user account definitely has a password set.

My database name is `hashim_wordpress`, my user account is Hashim, and my password is definitely correct. phpMyAdmin lists my server as `127.0.0.1`, but I've also tried `localhost`. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: By default, Xampp sets up the MySQL username as "root" with no password. Unless you have manually created a MySQL user with your username - which is not the same as your Windows username - try "root" as the username in wp-config.php.

Comment: @WebElaine As I already mentioned in the question, I followed the linked steps to create a MySQL database and user account.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your phpmyadmin window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue was the user's *Host name* field.

From the PHPMyAdmin dashboard, go to *User accounts*, select *Edit privileges* for the user that you previously created, and select the *Login Information* tab.

Here, there'll be a field called *Host name* with a dropdown menu and a text field:

[image]

By default this dropdown is set to `Any host`, and the host name itself as `%`.

However, what Wordpress' documentation fails to make mention of is that the `%` hostname doesn't allow for local development, despite the fact that this is probably the most common way to develop with Wordpress.

This is because `%` doesn't include `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, as explained in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user/10823868).

### Resolving the issue

This is now easily solved by creating a new user account with the same permissions as the current one, while changing its host name of `localhost`. The old, broken user account is deleted for the sake of tidiness.

For the user account in question, change the drop down in the *Host name* field to `Local` - this will automatically set the host name to `localhost`:

[image]

In the field below, select *delete the old one from the user tables*, and click the *Go* button to push the changes:

[image]

After doing this, I was able to navigate to `localhost/wordpress` and enter my credentials as normal, resulting in a successful local installation of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **127.0.0.1:3306** instead of using **localhost**.

**:3306** is the default port when using PHP7. That should do it.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: No such luck, unfortunately. Same with `localhost:3306`. I was so sure this was it.

Comment: Darn, what a pitty.